# Switch on enum with default case won't compile.

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I'm attempting to use a switch statement over an enumeration as follows:-

```
public enum myEnum
{
    This = 0,
    That = 1,
    TheOther = 2
}

private void doo_foo (myEnum input)
{
    switch (input)
    {
        case myEnum.This:
            // do something;
            break;
        case myEnum.That:
            // do something;
            break;
        case myEnum.TheOther:
            // do something
            break;
        case default:
            // do something;
            break;
    }
}
```

but this returns a compilation error on the `case default:` line:-

> Syntax error, '(' expected.

with the little red underline under the colon. Can anyone see what the matter is?

Comment: Take a look on [switch statement syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Drop the `case` from the `default` line:

```
switch (input)
{
    case myEnum.This:
        // do something;
        break;
    case myEnum.That:
        // do something;
        break;
    case myEnum.TheOther:
        // do something
        break;
    default:
        // do something;
        break;
}
```

Comment: Groan. Been staring at that for over an hour, and couldn't see it. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

As Rob Lyndon already answered, the correct syntax is just `default:`. But to also explain the error message you get, `case default` is a valid start of a `case default(int):` expression (which means `case 0:`), but in order to be valid, `default` needs to be followed by an opening parenthesis, and that's what the error message is reporting.